# Scaling member portal user base

Tags: user-account, hosting

I am curious to what organizations consider a large member portal user base? Have you run into any issues scaling?

We estimate ~256MB per backend Civi user (for an intensive user). Since a member portal user will be prevented from interacting with Civi directly ( and no wp-admin access), what resource allocation should we estimate per member portal user?

We are using WP multisite and [CiviCRM WordPress Member Sync](https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-wp-member-sync/). The portal is on the main site only.

Comment: Not an answer, but when looking at number of contacts, the stats site helps gauge where you are on the size spectrum http://stats.civicrm.org/?tab=sites

Comment: This isn't really a question about CiviCRM resource usage, what you care about is resource usage of WP. You say above that portal users won't be interacting with CiviCRM, right? Resource usage is pretty difficult to estimate reliably - there are formulas that will give you an upper bound, but it's only in actual live production that you can tell how often your users will login. And there are tradeoffs - a faster processor will result in fewer concurrent requests, so you can get away with less memory, for example.